# How do I read tabulator separated CSV in blaze?

Tags: pandas, blaze, dask

I have a "CSV" data file with the following format (well, it's rather a TSV):

```
event  pdg x   y   z   t   px  py  pz  ekin
3383    11  -161.515    5.01938e-05 -0.000187112    0.195413    0.664065    0.126078    -0.736968   0.00723234  
1694    11  -161.515    -0.000355633    0.000263174 0.195413    0.511853    -0.523429   0.681196    0.00472714  
4228    11  -161.535    6.59631e-06 -3.32796e-05    0.194947    -0.713983   -0.0265468  -0.69966    0.0108681   
4233    11  -161.515    -0.000524488    6.5069e-05  0.195413    0.942642    0.331324    0.0406377   0.017594
```

This file is interpretable as-is in `pandas`:

```
from pandas import read_csv, read_table
data = read_csv("test.csv", sep="\t", index_col=False)     # Works
data = read_table("test.csv", index_col=False)             # Works
```

However, when I try to read it in `blaze` (that declares to use pandas keyword arguments), an exception is thrown:

```
from blaze import Data 
Data("test.csv")                             # Attempt 1
Data("test.csv", sep="\t")                   # Attempt 2
Data("test.csv", sep="\t", index_col=False)  # Attempt 3
```

None of these works and pandas is not used at all. The "sniffer" that tries to deduce column names and types just calls `csv.Sniffer.sniff()` from standard library (which fails).

Is there a way how to properly read this file in blaze (given that its "little brother" has few hundred MBs, I want to use blaze's sequential processing capabilities)?

Thanks for any ideas.

**Edit:** I think it might be a problem of odo/csv and filed an issue: https://github.com/blaze/odo/issues/327

**Edit2:** 
Complete error:

```
Error Traceback (most recent call last)  in () ----> 1 bz.Data("test.csv", sep="\t", index_col=False)

/home/[username-hidden]/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/blaze/interactive.py in Data(data, dshape, name, fields, columns, schema, **kwargs)
     54     if isinstance(data, _strtypes):
     55         data = resource(data, schema=schema, dshape=dshape, columns=columns,
---> 56                         **kwargs)
     57     if (isinstance(data, Iterator) and
     58             not isinstance(data, tuple(not_an_iterator))):

/home/[username-hidden]/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/odo/regex.py in __call__(self, s, *args, **kwargs)
     62 
     63     def __call__(self, s, *args, **kwargs):
---> 64         return self.dispatch(s)(s, *args, **kwargs)
     65 
     66     @property

/home/[username-hidden]/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/odo/backends/csv.py in resource_csv(uri, **kwargs)
    276 @resource.register('.+\.(csv|tsv|ssv|data|dat)(\.gz|\.bz2?)?')
    277 def resource_csv(uri, **kwargs):
--> 278     return CSV(uri, **kwargs)
    279 
    280 

/home/[username-hidden]/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/odo/backends/csv.py in __init__(self, path, has_header, encoding, sniff_nbytes, **kwargs)
    102         if has_header is None:
    103             self.has_header = (not os.path.exists(path) or
--> 104                                infer_header(path, sniff_nbytes))
    105         else:
    106             self.has_header = has_header

/home/[username-hidden]/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/odo/backends/csv.py in infer_header(path, nbytes, encoding, **kwargs)
     58     with open_file(path, 'rb') as f:
     59         raw = f.read(nbytes)
---> 60     return csv.Sniffer().has_header(raw if PY2 else raw.decode(encoding))
     61 
     62 

/home/[username-hidden]/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/csv.py in has_header(self, sample)
    392         # subtracting from the likelihood of the first row being a header.
    393 
--> 394         rdr = reader(StringIO(sample), self.sniff(sample))
    395 
    396         header = next(rdr) # assume first row is header

/home/[username-hidden]/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/csv.py in sniff(self, sample, delimiters)
    187 
    188         if not delimiter:
--> 189             raise Error("Could not determine delimiter")
    190 
    191         class dialect(Dialect):

Error: Could not determine delimiter
```

Comment: Hi, there. I believe that this worked on my system. What are the errors you are getting?

Comment: Seems like installing dask changed the error being reported to something else. I am a bit confused. I'll leave it for now and parse the data with just pandas - I need the analysis to be done in a few hours. I'll come back to this later. Thanks.

Comment: See the edits to my post. Your columns are not parsed correctly in the purely pandas analysis.

Comment: I edited the original code a few minutes after posting (see ;-)). So yes, you are right about pandas parsing. But this alas is not the problem :-(

Comment: My point is sep='\t' does not work

Comment: Oh, I see. In fact, it works. Problem of Ctrl-C, Ctrl-V, sorry... In the original file, there are really tabs.

Comment: Can you post a link to a gist of the file?

Comment: Sure, it's here: http://pastebin.com/03zcPsTX

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am working with *Python* 2.7.10, *dask* v0.7.1, *blaze* v0.8.2 and *conda* v3.17.0.

```
conda install dask
conda install blaze
```

Here is a way you can import the data for use with *blaze*. Parse the data first with *pandas* and then convert it into *blaze*. Perhaps this defeats the purpose, but there are no troubles this way.

As a side note in order to parse the data file correctly your line in pandas parse statment should be:

```
from blaze import Data
from pandas import DataFrame, read_csv
data = read_csv("csvdata.dat", sep="\s*", index_col=False)
bdata = Data(data)
```

Now the data is formatted correctly with no errors, `bdata`:

```
   event  pdg        x         y         z         t        px        py  \
0   3383   11 -161.515  0.000050 -0.000187  0.195413  0.664065  0.126078   
1   1694   11 -161.515 -0.000356  0.000263  0.195413  0.511853 -0.523429   
2   4228   11 -161.535  0.000007 -0.000033  0.194947 -0.713983 -0.026547   
3   4233   11 -161.515 -0.000524  0.000065  0.195413  0.942642  0.331324   

     pz      ekin  
0 -0.736968  0.007232  
1  0.681196  0.004727  
2 -0.699660  0.010868
```

Here is an alternative, use dask, it probably can do the same chunking, or large scale processing you are looking for. Dask certainly makes it immediately easy to correctly load a tsv format.

```
In [17]: import dask.dataframe as dd

In [18]: df = dd.read_csv('tsvdata.txt', sep='\t', index_col=False)

In [19]: df.head()
Out[19]: 
   event  pdg        x         y         z         t        px        py  \
0   3383   11 -161.515  0.000050 -0.000187  0.195413  0.664065  0.126078   
1   1694   11 -161.515 -0.000356  0.000263  0.195413  0.511853 -0.523429   
2   4228   11 -161.535  0.000007 -0.000033  0.194947 -0.713983 -0.026547   
3   4233   11 -161.515 -0.000524  0.000065  0.195413  0.942642  0.331324   
4    854   11 -161.515  0.000032  0.000418  0.195414  0.675752  0.315671   

         pz      ekin  
0 -0.736968  0.007232  
1  0.681196  0.004727  
2 -0.699660  0.010868  
3  0.040638  0.017594  
4 -0.666116  0.012641  

In [20]:
```

See also: http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/array-blaze.html#how-to-use-blaze-with-dask

Comment: Heureka! Dask is the way out :-)